# Order Command in Factor Data Type

Tags: r, data-structures

```
Res_FB = c("veryhappy","happy","unhappy")
Res_FB
class(Res_FB)
Res_FB_fact = as.factor(Res_FB)
Res_FB_fact
class(Res_FB_fact)
as.integer(Res_FB_fact)
```

Please need help. It is an assignment in my class.

When i RUN "as.integer(Res_FB_fact)" the outcome is 3, 1, 2 for veryhappy , happy and unhappy respectively.

Case: It is the feed back of an restaurant customers.

Now i want to change the order of integers assigned by the system automatically. I want to assign 1 for Very happy, 2 for happy and 3 for unhappy.

Can someone please help me with the using "order" command in this case.

Very Thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the order of the factors. You can specify it by hand, as I did, or use some sort of ordering.

```
res.new <- factor(Res_FB, levels = c("veryhappy", "happy", "unhappy"))
as.integer(res.new)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Veryhelpful